# Can not deploy my contract on ganache-cli using ETH mainnet fork

Tags: fork, solidity, truffle, ganache

I used ganache-cli in combination with my Infura key to fork ETH mainnet so I could use the Uniswap router in my development environment:

`ganache-cli --fork https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<mykeyhere>`

This starts my local ganache blockchain without any errors. However when I deploy my [contract](https://pastebin.com/fhFxWg77) with truffle:

`truffle(development)> deploy`

I keep getting the following error:

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
✓ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1
✓ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1
> Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/MollyCoin.sol
> Artifacts written to /home/dogperson/Code/MollyCoin/build/contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.6.12+commit.27d51765.Emscripten.clang

UnhandledRejections detected
Promise {
  <rejected> CodedError: Given input "NaN" is not a number.
      at /home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/handlers/base-handler.js:174:23
      at process.promise (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
      at ProviderHandler.queueRequest (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/handlers/base-handler.js:178:36)
      at ProviderHandler.request (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/handlers/provider-handler.js:58:9)
      at earliestBlock (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/persistent-cache/helpers.js:149:5)
      at previousClosestAncestor (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/persistent-cache/helpers.js:77:19)
      at PersistentCache.cache [as initialize] (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/persistent-cache/persistent-cache.js:142:47)
      at Fork.cache [as initCache] (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/fork.js:209:21)
      at Fork.fallback [as initialize] (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/fork.js:206:13)
      at Blockchain.async [as initialize] (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/blockchain.js:629:22)
      at EthereumProvider.async [as initialize] (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/provider.js:195:5)
      at Connector.connect (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/connector.js:49:5) {
    code: -32000
  }
} CodedError: Given input "NaN" is not a number.
    at /home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/handlers/base-handler.js:174:23
    at process.promise (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at ProviderHandler.queueRequest (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/handlers/base-handler.js:178:36)
    at ProviderHandler.request (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/handlers/provider-handler.js:58:9)
    at earliestBlock (/home/dogperson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/webpack:/Ganache/chains/ethereum/ethereum/lib/src/forking/persistent-cache/helpers.js
```

The contract deploys just fine if I run ganache-cli without --fork. Also if I connect Remix to my forked ganache-cli through Metamask, I am also able to deploy and interact with the contract just fine, which makes me believe that the issue might be with truffle.

Extra info:
Truffle version: 5.5.13
[Truffle config file](https://pastebin.com/iF77sF7S)

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I am seeing exactly the same...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the same thing as you and encountered the same error.

After some research I believe the issue is that ganache is read-only when used to fork mainnet (or any testnet). You can't make any transactions. Only calls.

I was able to achieve the objective by using Hardhat instead of ganache.

First I installed hardhat and initialized the sample project:
https://hardhat.org/guides/project-setup.html

Then I ran hardhat with:

```
npx hardhat node --fork "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<ACCOUNT>"
```

Then I ran "truffle console" in a separate terminal window, with the following lines in truffle-config.js:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const mnemonic = "test test test test test test test test test test test junk";
module.exports = {
    networks: {
        development: {
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            port: 8545,
            network_id: "*",
            provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "http://127.0.0.1:8545"),
        }
    }
}
```

The mnemonic I used is "test test test test test test test test test test test junk" because that is Hardhat's default mnemonic and I was not immediately able to figure out how to configure Hardhat with a different mnemonic.

Before running the truffle console, remember to install the hdwalletprovider npm package in your truffle directory: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/hdwallet-provider

At this point I have a running truffle console connected to local hardhat process which is connected to infura. I can make transactions to deploy and interact with contracts.

Hope this helps, and good luck.

Comment: I'm also getting this error, but am able to deploy my contract just fine to ganache by using Hardhat to execute the deployment.